# PyCurl TypeError: invalid argument to setopt

Tags: python, post, curl, pycurl

I'm using PyCurl to send POST request with file as an attachment:

```
d = pycurl.Curl()
d.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
# d.setopt(pycurl.RETURNTRANSFER, True)
d.setopt(pycurl.POST, True)
d.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, {filename: "@" + filename})
b = StringIO.StringIO()
d.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, b.write)
d.perform()
d.close()
message = b.getvalue()
```

and I get:

```
Something went wrong, invalid arguments to setopt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hasoff.py", line 214, in create_offers_for_advertiser
    if filename:
TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`pycurl.POSTFIELDS` needs URL-encoded data. [From docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#sending-form-data):

```
post_data = {'field': 'value'}
postfields = urlencode(post_data)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postfields)
```

You can't send file using `pycurl.POSTFIELDS`.

File can be send using  `pycurl.HTTPPOST`. [From docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/quickstart.html#file-upload):

```
c.setopt(c.HTTPPOST, [
    ('fileupload', (
        c.FORM_FILE, __file__,
        c.FORM_FILENAME, 'helloworld.py',
        c.FORM_CONTENTTYPE, 'application/x-python',
    )),
])
```

Comment: @paus this example is written on PHP, not Python. Curl API is different for this languages. You can't use PHP specific `@$filename` with `pycurl`.